# Differential subbundles of trivial bundle over a segment.

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $F \subset (0,1)\times \mathbb R^n$ be a differential vector subbundle of rank $r$ of trivial vector bundle over the segment $(0,1)$. I'd like to prove that, if for every differential section $\sigma$ of $F$, $\frac{d\sigma}{dt}$ is also a section of $F$, then $F$ is a trivial subbundle. I have a hint that I should use constant rank theorem but I can't realize how to use it there.

Comment: Every vector bundle on an interval is trivial, so you probably want to show that it is a trivial *differential bundle" in which case you should define precisely what you mean by that.

Comment: @user72694 I mean that $F$ is trivial as subbundle, i.e. $F = (0,1) \times \mathbb R^r \subset (0,1) \times \mathbb R^n$

Comment: This is still ambiguous.  You certainly don't mean a coordinate $R^r$.  Do you mean that the fiber is a fixed linear subspace of $R^n$? You should state so then.  Most people will understand "trivial" to mean "diffeomorphic to a product".